# How do remote access devices work without a cellular connection or internet

Tags: wifi, remote-control

[This](http://www.cabelas.com/product/Hunting/Scouting-Feeders/Trail-Cameras-Accessories%7C/pc/104791680/c/104767380/sc/103867380/Wildgame-Innovations-Wi-Fi-Module/1221386.uts?destination=%2Fcatalog%2Fbrowse%2Fhunting-scouting-feeders-trail-cameras-accessories%2Fwildgame-innovations%2F_%2FN-1100176%2B1000005156%2FNe-1000005156%3FWT.mc_id%3Dgoogle%257Chun_Wildlife%2BManagement_Trail%2BCameras%257CUSA%26WT.srch%3D1%26WT.tsrc%3DPPC%26WT.z_mc_id1%3D43000000117920799%26WTz_st%3DGuidedNav%26WTz_stype%3DGNU%26pcrid%3D8194945977%26rid%3D20&WTz_l=PPC%3Bcat103867380) is a sample of one such device i am talking about, i seen a wireless "external hard drive" like electronic at best buy that you can access movies from it without wifi and i have been constantly trying to understand how it works. Please help curb my curiosity.

Comment: Are you loony?? Throwing a *555 character URL* in our face like that! ***Please*** use hyperlinks the proper way. Oh yes, by the way,welcome to EE! :-)

Answer (score 2):

> ...you can use this system independent from cellular networks because it sets up your own Wi-Fi hotspot similar to a wireless network in your home

It seems to set up a **wireless adhoc (independent) network** , to which other wireless-enabled devices like smartphones and computers can connect. (Note that this is different from connecting to an existing infrastructure network/access-point.) You can read the [Wikipedia article on Wireless ad-hoc networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_ad-hoc_network).

If you are asking because you're interested in setting up something similar, note that wireless module units with ad-hoc capability, are available widely, for example [this one](http://www.rovingnetworks.com/products/RN_XV).

Comment: Thanks for the help, i was just curious on how it worked. I figured it generated its own signal but being new to electronics i was unsure of how it worked. Thanks again